# Spread of a disease on a modular chessboard (torus) - lower bound

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, puzzle, lower-bounds, cellular-automata

I learned about the following result from one of Peter Winkler's books:

*It is impossible to infect the entire $n\times n$ chessboard (usual chessboard) starting from fewer than $n$ infected cells.*

The infection is a deterministic process: a healthy cell that is neighboring at least $2$ infected cells becomes infected. Two cells are neighbors if they share one side. The technique that was proposed to prove the lower bound relies on the property that the perimeter of the infected area does not increase.

If we set the same problem (same infection rule and neighborhood definition) on a torus (by joining opposite sides of the chessboard), I noticed that $n-1$ infected cells are sufficient to infect the entire torus. However, I was not able to prove that it's impossible to infect the entire torus using fewer than $n-1$ infected cells, which seems to stand for some instances of $n$ at least. I tried to find similar *'invariant arguments'* as the perimeter argument mentioned above, but settled with nothing. Does anyone know a similar technique to solve this problem?

Comment: Crossposted from math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988288/infection-spread-on-a-torus-chessboard

Comment: …and puzzling.SE: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106444/infected-cylinder-and-torus

Comment: @Steve: Please see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se (and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). In particular, if you feel you really need to ask the same question on multiple sites, please at least do it openly and cross-link your questions so that other people won't waste their time writing redundant answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I was not aware of the policy. Is it possible to delete this question then? I don't seem to find a way.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/help/deleted-questions

Comment: Wow! This is pretty much a copy of what I posted in math.stackexchange! :-)

Comment: An accepted answer is posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3988288/522463